# AD Authentication Unknown username or bad password

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, active-directory, asp.net-membership

I am using VS2005 C#.

I am trying to switch my login authentication from the ASP.NET Web Site Administration Tool from using *Internet* to *Local Network*, which is the Windows authentication.

I have set the MembershipProvider of my Login tool in my web form to my MP name, *MyADMembershipProvider*.

Below is my current *web.config* file after making some changes:

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings/>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="SODConnectionString" connectionString="CONNECTIONSTRING" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

        <add name="ADConnectionString" connectionString="LDAP://URL"/>
    </connectionStrings>
    <system.web>
        <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <roleManager enabled="true" />
    <pages styleSheetTheme="DataWebControls"/>
        <membership defaultProvider="MyADMembershipProvider">
            <providers>
                <clear/>
                <add name="MyADMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=PUBTOKEN" applicationName="SOD" connectionStringName="ADConnectionString" connectionUsername="domain\Username" connectionPassword="Password" attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName" enableSearchMethods="true" />
            </providers>

        </membership>
        <siteMap defaultProvider="XmlSiteMapProvider" enabled="true">
            <providers>
                <add name="XmlSiteMapProvider"
      description="Default SiteMap provider."
      type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider"
      siteMapFile="Web.sitemap"
      securityTrimmingEnabled="true" />
            </providers>
        </siteMap>
            <compilation debug="true"/>
            <!-- Turn on Custom Errors -->
        <customErrors defaultRedirect="~/Error/NetworkError.aspx" mode="On">
   <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/PageNotFound.aspx" />
  </customErrors>
    </system.web>
</configuration>`
```

I am currently receiving a configuration parse error message: *Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password* when I tried to log on with my Windows credentials of my machine within the intranet.

The error pointed out line

```
<add name="MyADMembershipProvider" 
     type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" 
     applicationName="SOD" 
     connectionStringName="ADConnectionString" 
     connectionUsername="domain\Username" 
     connectionPassword="Password" 
     attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName" 
     enableSearchMethods="true" />
```

has an error.

May I know which part of my code went wrong?

---

**EDIT:**

I have filled in the actual credentials for the code

```
connectionUsername="domain\Username" connectionPassword="Password"
```

I am now able to login with the correct credentials, and I am also prompted wrong credential for incorrect log in attempts.

When another user of different credential from the one I 'hardcoded' in the `connectionUsername` and `connectionPassword`, the user is still able to log on.

However, my *LoginName* tool from the toolbox still shows the username of the 'hardcoded' credentials in the `connectionUsername` instead of the username of the logged in user.

May I know why is it so?

Comment: Have you changed the auth settings on your site/application/virtual directory/page to "Windows Authentication" (assuming you're hosting with IIS)?

Comment: @M.Babcock may I know how do I go to site/application/virtual directory/page? Is it by the control panal or?

Comment: It would be in your IIS Manager.

Comment: @M.Babcock do i need an external tool for it?

Comment: @M.Babcock i have not configured any ISS manager till now. May I know how can i open the tool?

Comment: IIS Manager is a component generally installed with IIS. `Win`+`R` then type `inetmgr`.

Comment: @M.Babcock I couldn't locate `inetmgr`. Is it the same as finding for `mmc`?

Comment: [Here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754628(WS.10).aspx) is a tutorial for configuring Windows authentication in IIS 7. [Here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770472(WS.10).aspx) is another tutorial for opening IIS manager for IIS 7. If you need another version, google will be your friend.

Comment: are the guides compatible with windows xp?

Comment: What version of IIS are you running on XP?

Comment: I have checked my machine, and I do not have IIS installed. Is it compulsory to run IIS for ActiveDirectory authentication?

Comment: Not necessarily. What web server *are* you using? *(Ignoring the fact that I said my first comment only mattered if you were using IIS)*

Comment: **SQL** Server is not a **Web** server.

Comment: Any progress on figuring out the IIS version?

Comment: @M.Babcock I am still unable to get the ver. of the IIS as I require my senior in the company to check for me and he is not around today. I have edited my post with some updates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the error is with the membership provider and not specifically with the logon.

It looks to me that the connectionUsername and connectionPassword properties in the membership provider are not specifying a valid AD account. I believe this account is used to verify the credentials during the logon process and to retrieve information about the account once it is logged on.

Comment: I have specified an AD account in `connectionUsername` and `connectionPassword`. However after logging in, the *loginName* tool only show the username of the AD account instead of the username of the logged in user. May I know why is it so?

Comment: Have you tried logging onto the machine with the account you've specified? I still suspect something is wrong with that account - bad password, suspended account, not enough security authority, etc. @RUiHAO, What is the loginName tool?